# RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.OperationInterruptedException errors are logged in pods

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

In my project which is based on Micro-services and each micro services are deployed on K8s. When I checking the pods logs, I got to see the following logs related to those services.

This is the part of the Notification service logs.

```
fail: MassTransit[0]
      Declare queue faulted: name: NotificationRequest, durable
      RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.OperationInterruptedException: The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by Peer, code=404, text='NOT_FOUND - home node 'rabbit@rabbitmq-apps-cluster-server-0.rabbitmq-apps-cluster-nodes.rabbitmq-clusters' of durable queue 'NotificationRequest' in vhost '/' is down or inaccessible', classId=50, methodId=10
         at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SimpleBlockingRpcContinuation.GetReply(TimeSpan timeout)
         at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.ModelBase.QueueDeclare(String queue, Boolean passive, Boolean durable, Boolean exclusive, Boolean autoDelete, IDictionary`2 arguments)
         at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.ModelBase.QueueDeclare(String queue, Boolean durable, Boolean exclusive, Boolean autoDelete, IDictionary`2 arguments)
         at MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Contexts.RabbitMqModelContext.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.ModelContext.QueueDeclare>b__0()
         at MassTransit.Util.ChannelExecutor.SynchronousFuture`1.Run()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at MassTransit.Util.ChannelExecutor.Run[T](Func`1 method, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Pipeline.ConfigureTopologyFilter`1.Declare(ModelContext context, Queue queue)
fail: MassTransit[0]
      Declare queue faulted: name: SmsRequest, durable
      RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.OperationInterruptedException: The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by Peer, code=404, text='NOT_FOUND - home node 'rabbit@rabbitmq-apps-cluster-server-0.rabbitmq-apps-cluster-nodes.rabbitmq-clusters' of durable queue 'SmsRequest' in vhost '/' is down or inaccessible', classId=50, methodId=10
         at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SimpleBlockingRpcContinuation.GetReply(TimeSpan timeout)
         at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.ModelBase.QueueDeclare(String queue, Boolean passive, Boolean durable, Boolean exclusive, Boolean autoDelete, IDictionary`2 arguments)
         at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.ModelBase.QueueDeclare(String queue, Boolean durable, Boolean exclusive, Boolean autoDelete, IDictionary`2 arguments)
         at MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Contexts.RabbitMqModelContext.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.ModelContext.QueueDeclare>b__0()
         at MassTransit.Util.ChannelExecutor.SynchronousFuture`1.Run()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at MassTransit.Util.ChannelExecutor.Run[T](Func`1 method, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Pipeline.ConfigureTopologyFilter`1.Declare(ModelContext context, Queue queue)
```

And this is how configured the Masstransit in the startup.

```
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.AddConsumer<NotificationRequestConsumer>();
    x.AddConsumer<EmailRequestConsumer>();
    x.AddConsumer<SmsRequestConsumer>();
    x.AddBus(context => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(c =>
    {
        c.Host(configuration["RabbitMQ:HostUrl"]);
        c.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
    }));
    x.AddRequestClient<CustomerDetailsReq>(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(80));
    x.AddRequestClient<CardDetailReq>(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(80));
    x.AddRequestClient<InvestmentDetailNewRequest>();
});

services.AddMassTransitHostedService();
```

Explain the reason for this. What should be done to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like your RabbitMQ cluster is broken.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson if yes, then how functionality working fine? any way to determine the exact reason from the K8 side?

Comment: Well the error is from the cluster: `NOT_FOUND - home node 'rabbit@rabbitmq-apps-cluster-server-0.rabbitmq-apps-cluster-nodes.rabbitmq-clusters' of durable queue 'SmsRequest' in vhost '/' is down or inaccessible`